# teechart backimage inside does not work in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-xe4

In Teecharts you can include a background image. In previous versions of the steema product you could force the backimage to be inside the graphing panel. The options (backimageinside = true) is still there but the effect is nothing is shown.

any help greatly appreciated.

Han

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work fine for me with both the latest Pro version available and also with the Standard version shipped with XE4.

```
uses jpeg;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.BackImage.LoadFromFile('C:\tmp\flower.jpg');
  Chart1.BackImageInside:=true;
end;
```